# $T:P_3 → P_3$ be the linear transformation such that...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:P_3 \to P_3$ be the linear transformation such that $T(2 x^2)= -2 x^2 - 4 x$, $T(-0.5 x - 5)= 2 x^2 + 4 x + 3$, and $T(2 x^2 - 1) = 4 x - 4.$
Find $T(1)$, $T(x)$, $T(x^2)$, and $T(a x^2 + b x + c)$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: Can you express $1$ and $x^2$ as linear combinations of $2x^2$ and $2x^2-1$ and build it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint:T is linear transformation $T(a+bx+cx^2)=aT(1)+bT(x) +cT(x^2) $ $$T(2 x^2)= -2 x^2 - 4 x \to T( x^2)= - x^2 - 2 x$$$$T(-0.5 x - 5)= 2 x^2 + 4 x + 3\to-0.5T( x) - 5T(1)= 2 x^2 + 4 x + 3\to 16x^2+72x-46$$$$T(2 x^2 - 1) = 4 x - 4.\to T( x^2) - \frac12T(1) = 2 x - 2\to T(1)=-2 x^2 - 8x +4.$$